How to create one-to-many relationship in a flask project using the SQLAlchemy
I am new to learning Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy. I have a project and I need to create one-to-many relationship beetwen class User and class Place
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    UID = db.Column(db.Integer, unique = True, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    login = db.Column(db.String(), unique = True,)
    password = db.Column(db.String())

class Place(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "places"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key = True, unique = True)
    name_of_place = db.Column(db.String(), unique = True)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer())
    desired_season = db.Column(db.String())
    term = db.Column(db.String())

I need to have multiple places assigned to each user

Does this answer your question? How to create one-to-many relationships in SQLAlchemy Flask
